# Missing Librarries and unsure as to which ones?

Tags: 12.04, libraries

I have a very small and simple program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream inf("artists.txt");
  char* moneyshot;
  inf >> moneyshot;
  cout << moneyshot;
  return 0;
}
```

And I have it working on the labs at school.

But on my machine it seg faults.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de87ca in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

I used gdb and realized it was doing this at the cout line, and I can ony conclude that I'm missing libraries, I'm unsure as to which ones and I was wondering how to find the missing ones and how to get them?

Answer (score 0):

You may need C++ libraries which comes along with g++ (GNU c++ compiler, which you require as well I guess).

Install using `sudo apt-get install g++`

But It would be best to install all basic development tools using

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

I am not sure that you are missing libraries. You should not get segfault on missing libraries. Compiler will not compile it then. What is that `inf`? `ifstream` doesn't have [any reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) to it. Check the program once. I am not an expert in c++. So can't really help you here.

Comment: I've already done both, still seg faulting.